# Select data from same field but in two different rows, then output to one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a follow table that has follower and a followee fields that represents user_id in a user table.   The user table has the names of the users, called full_name.   I want to create a query that pushes an update from a post table to all followees when a follower posts.  Results to to look like this:

> user.full_name of followee, user.fullname of follower, update of followee.

Code I have is:

```
SELECT user.user_id, user.user_id, post.update
FROM follow
    JOIN  post ON post.user_id = follow.follower_user_id
    JOIN  user ON user.user_id = follow.followee_user_id
Where update.date  > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 DAY)
GROUP BY follow.followee_user_id
```

It does the right query, but I can't get the follower name to populate.  it just duplicates the followee.  Any idea on how to write the select fields?

Answer (score 1):

You need *two* joins on the `user` table - one for the follower and one for the followee:

```
SELECT followee_user.full_name AS followee_name, 
    follower_user.full_name AS follower_name, 
    post.update
FROM follow
INNER JOIN user AS followee_user 
    ON follow.followee_user_id = followee_user.user_id
INNER JOIN user AS follower_user 
    ON follow.follower_user_id = follower_user.user_id
INNER JOIN post ON follow.followee_user_id = post.user_id
WHERE post.update > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
```

Note that you *must* provide aliases for each instance of the joined `user` table to disambiguate the two. In this case I have used "`followee_user`" and "`follower_user`".

I am not sure what `update.date` is so I have assumed it is a typo and you meant `update`; change this as necessary. Also the `GROUP BY` does not make any sense here so I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to the user table **two** times, once for the follower role, and once for the followee role... something like this:

```
 SELECT e.full_name AS followee_full_name
      , r.full_name AS follower_full_name
      , p.update
   FROM follow f
   JOIN post p ON p.user_id = f.follower_user_id
   JOIN user r ON r.user_id = f.follower_user_id
   JOIN user e ON e.user_id = f.followee_user_id
  WHERE p.update_date  > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

Comment: sorry but i think it is the same answer given by lc.

Comment: @Dhaval: possibly. i'm not sure this returns the resultset specified, without the actual table definitions and sample data. But it looks like both `followee_user_id` and `follower_user_id` are foreign keys to the `user` table.  I think lc has the same pattern in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and identical to the answer another person provided almost at the same time.  It works like a charm!   Thanks so much!